# Calling repaint() For JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, repaint

When I repaint() the panel, where I'm placing my JLabels on, I get errors, but it still works.  I tried putting the panel.repaint(); code in a try statement and that didn't help.  Anyone else having problems with repaint() for JPanels?

Error message (copied from the comments):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: No such child: 21 
at java.awt.Container.getComponent(Unknown Source) 
at javax.swing.JComponent.rectangleIsObscured(Unknown Source) 
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) 
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source) 
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source) 
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source) )
```

Comment: Do you know what the errors are?

Comment: What are the errors? Are you drawing on the panel? if so consider overriding paintComponent method instead of paint method and make sure you always call super.paintComponent(g);

Comment: the error message is too big for one comment 
Part1
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: No such child: 21
 at java.awt.Container.getComponent(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.rectangleIsObscured(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)

)

Comment: Post the full error message in your *original question*. You can edit the question easily and just paste it in. Then highlight the code and push the code formatting button/link. Also show the code that is causing the error. As for "is anyone else having problems" we can't help if you don't tell the details of what your problem is. You've got a bug in your code and you need to show it to us if we're going to have a chance of helping you.

Comment: Now consider posting your offending code.

Comment: Sounds like a Swing threading issue, are you doing all your UI work on the Swing EDT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that all modifications to the UI are carried out in the Event Dispatching Thread, this includes adding and removing components from containers.

As Leon states, using the `invokeLater` method will ensure that operations are carried on the EDT correctly.

Comment: how does the invokeLater method work, and how does one implement it?

Comment: InvokeLater basically places a Runnable object onto the ETD queue, allowing it to be executed at some time in the future (within in the ETD).  Basically, you need to call SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...) and pass a Object that implements the Runnable interface.  When the ETD processes the queue, it will call the "run" method.

Comment: You can check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html for some more details

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure but I think I stumbled upon the same problem before. I believed using SwingUtilities.invokeLater helped me backed then. 
Give it a try, I'm not just exactly sure.